# Tuple Problem @model Tuple<HabasPortal.Models.Profile,List<SelectListItem>>

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, view, model, database-first

I use **database first** on my project.I wil save to **Profile table** and fill a **dropdown** from **department table** on this page . How do I use both `profile.cs` and `department.cs` in a view in `Profile.cshtml`? It is a Creating page.

This is `Profile.cs` ;

```
public partial class Profile
{
    public int ProfileID { get; set; }
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }
    public string Office { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string MobileNumber { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public bool Status { get; set; }
    public string Note { get; set; }
    public byte[] Image { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> RecordDate { get; set; }

}
```

This is `Department.cs` ;

```
public partial class Department
{
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Is there anyone to answer ?

Comment: So what is the problem with `Tuple`?

Comment: I tried a lot of ways, but I got an error. How do you refer to two different classes in the view using the Database First method?

Comment: I want to pull the data from the Department class in the Dropdownlist and select this incoming data and transfer it to the Profile class.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.

ProfileController.cs

```
 public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.departman = new SelectList(db.Departments.ToList(), "DepartmentID", "DepartmentName");
        return View();
    }
```

Create.cshtml

```
@Html.DropDownList("Department", ViewBag.departman as SelectList)
```